# Why requestScope attribute is null and not null at the same time?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, requestdispatcher

Why requestScope is null and not null at the same time?
this is part of a code of index.jsp file

```
<c:if test="${!pageContext.request.servletPath.equals('/Login')}">

    <c:if test = "${requestScope.Cars!=null}">
        <%
            List<Car>  cars = (ArrayList<Car>)request.getAttribute("Cars");
            System.out.println(cars.get(0));
        %>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${requestScope.Cars==null}">
        <%
            System.out.println(request.getAttribute("Cars")+" test");
        %>
        <jsp:forward page="/AllCarCategories"/>
    </c:if>

</c:if>
```

the first if statement was just to check how it can be null and not null at the same time

this is what AllCarCategories looks like

```
@WebServlet(name = "AllCarCategories", urlPatterns = {"/AllCarCategories","/Login/AllCarCategories"})
public class AllCarCategories extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MySQLDAOFactory dao =(MySQLDAOFactory) DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(1);
        MySQLCarDao carDao = (MySQLCarDao) dao.getCarDao();
        MySQLCarCategoryDao categoryDao = (MySQLCarCategoryDao)dao.getCarCategoryDao();
        List<CarCategory> carCategories = categoryDao.findAllCarC();
        List<Car> cars = carDao.findAllCars();
        System.out.println(carDao.findAllCars().size()+" size ");
        request.setAttribute("Cars",cars);
        request.setAttribute("Categories",carCategories);
        request.setAttribute("ImageMan", ImageManager.getInstance());
        System.out.println("request url:" +request.getRequestURL()+" requst servlet Path"+request.getServletPath());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);


    }

  
}
```

so at first time when its null im forwarding it to AllCarCategories and there list of Car objects is created, then im forwarding it to jsp file and by logic it cant be null because i created a List of Car objects but it is
And another mystery is that its enters in both if statements so its null and not null at the same time

this is what console outpuut looks like(Just to show what is going on there)
[image: Console output]

How it can be null and not null at the same time?Thanks

Comment: it can not possibly be null and not null at the same time.

Comment: but it is as i showed it above

Comment: no, you just think you showed it above, and you just think it is.

Comment: yes i showed it above and i curious about its being null and not null at the same time

Comment: those print statements aren't even in the same scope, let alone simultaneously. they're not "the same time" at all.

Comment: these print statements  are from idex.jsp and AllCarCategories so they are in the same scope

Comment: no, they aren't. several are from within the method you posted, others aren't that's not the same scope.

Comment: yes and the talk is about the ones that are in index.jsp so they are in the same scope and the ones that are  in AllCarCategories is just to check intermediate values and print it to the console output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232282/discussion-between-justtoasktheneededquestions-and-stultuske).

Comment: @Stultuske i edited post to show that they are in the same scope

Answer (score 0):

add an additional print before the first `if` testing for `null` (eventually one after second `if`) like

```
<c:if test="${!pageContext.request.servletPath.equals('/Login')}">
    <%
        System.out.println("new login");
    %>

    <c:if test = "${requestScope.Cars!=null}">
```

(just to show a bit more of information, not a real answer, and I do not develop JSP)